# Use CNN to forecast time series value accuracy problem

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, predictive-models, conv-neural-network, keras

I would like to use a CNN to predict a value based on some historical data. The concept is easy: I have a numerical value (label) the depends on some other numerical values (features). Each set of features is linked to just one label. From a set of features I want to predict the label.

This is the model schema I've imagined for the situation:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(Params.time_frame, Params.features)))

#model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(kernel_size=2, filters=256, strides=1, use_bias=True, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='VarianceScaling'))
#model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(kernel_size=2, filters=128, strides=1, use_bias=True, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='VarianceScaling'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(kernel_size=2, filters=64, strides=1, use_bias=True, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='VarianceScaling', padding='SAME'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(kernel_size=2, filters=32, strides=1, use_bias=True, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='VarianceScaling', padding='SAME'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(kernel_size=2, filters=16, strides=1, use_bias=True, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='VarianceScaling', padding='SAME'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(kernel_size=2, filters=8, strides=1, use_bias=True, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='VarianceScaling', padding='SAME'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(kernel_size=2, filters=4, strides=1, use_bias=True, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='VarianceScaling', padding='SAME'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, kernel_initializer='VarianceScaling',activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, kernel_initializer='VarianceScaling',activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='VarianceScaling',activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001), loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I'm using `TensorFlow` with `Keras`. Since I'm working with a time series I've used some 1-D Conv Layer. At the end I've tried to preserve the historical data with two fully connected Dense layers.

Now when I try to train the model I notice that `accuracy` metric never update after first two epochs:

```
Train on 4889 samples
Epoch 1/50
4889/4889 [==============================] - 1s 151us/sample - loss: 0.0416 - accuracy: 2.0454e-04
Epoch 2/50
4889/4889 [==============================] - 0s 80us/sample - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 4.0908e-04
Epoch 3/50
4889/4889 [==============================] - 0s 79us/sample - loss: 8.2775e-04 - accuracy: 4.0908e-04
...
Epoch 50/50
4889/4889 [==============================] - 0s 86us/sample - loss: 4.3382e-04 - accuracy: 4.0908e-04
```

Accuracy is also very low. So I think that there's must be a problem with the model structure. My knowledge in ML in currently basic, so I need an advice to keep the right direction.

Comment: I liked this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.04356

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression problem, so why are you using accuracy as a metric? It makes sense that your predictions will not exactly match the label value, as the output is continuous. So try MSE, RMSE, or some other continuous metric. Your loss function is converging, so there might not be a problem with the model structure at all.

Comment: Thanks! You really point me to the right direction. What do you think instead of the structure of the model? Should be fit the problem described?

Comment: Hey, thanks I'm glad I helped. Could you please upvote my comment? The shape of the model really depends on your data. If it is a time series, you may want to consider an RNN since it is able to look "backwards" or something like Facebook Prophet that fits to a Fourier series, if the data implies a seasonal trend.